# Android Studio v1.0.0 open project fail after upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I updated my Android Studio from version 0.86 to version 1.0.0.
I have followed all the steps described here : [migrating-android-studio](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0).

After many and many researches (upgrade gradle, invalidate cache, rebuilt project, restarted android-studio...)

My last stacktrace is the following:

> 2014-12-11 13:57:35,731 [2581696]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - No such property: transitive for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated 
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.LocationAwareExternalSystemException: No such property: transitive for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:103)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:358)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:368)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:474)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:645)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)

For your information my project is composed by 4 modules including 1 library.

Many thanks

Since 15/12/2014 I upgraded Android Studio in v1.0.1. Still the same stacktrace.

Comment: My advice is to stay with the old version, you created the project with, until they come up with the IDE support to help migrate the projects automatically. That's what I've done after a few failed migrations. Don't let the IDE take your 'work' time so much, like it did to me. We're supposed to concentrate on the programming work, not on the IDE. The entire purpose of an IDE is to make developing faster and easier, but not in this case.

Comment: It's finally what I decide to do. Downgrade my version from 1.0.1 to 0.89.